# Android - Know if 2 faces are equal

Tags: java, android, face-recognition

For my Android app I need to know if 2 faces are likely to correspond to the same person.
For example, I have an image of a person and then some other images of the same person, and I need to know whether the person is the same or not.
I have found the FaceDetector Android API, but it only detects faces.

Is there any API allowing me to do this? If not, is there any API that could give me parameters from a person's face and then compare those parameters?

Thank you.

Comment: `"I have found the FaceDetector Android API, but it only detects faces."` and

`"I need to know if 2 faces are likely to correspond to the same person."`.

I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use openCV library to make face recognation , here is a sample app based on openCV library : it detect the face and save it , and then make face recognation with tokken photo again in real time from camera :
https://github.com/Vinisoft/Face-Recognition-SDK-for-Android

Sorry for my english .